# CSS: Browser not calculating padding % correctly

Tags: css

I've written up a very basic HTML and CSS page to test out my responsive web design skills but the calculation of the padding is going wrong and I can't figure out why, any help from people would be greatly appreciated.

Below I have added my code for you to see. I have one 'main' with a 'section' and an 'aside' in it. Inside both are a box of two different sizes. I calculated the size and margin of the boxes ok but the padding won't work properly. I calculated the padding by target/context=result, which in this case for the first box is 25px padding / 500px = 0.05 (5%), and for the second box is 25px/300px= 0.08333333 (8.333333%).
However this does not cause a 25px padding but instead creates a much bigger one. When I look at the Google Chrome Developer Tool it tells me that the padding for the first box is now 56.875px and the second box is 94.797px.

I've been trying to solve this for sometime now trying different things but can't manage to figure it out.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Code is below.

```css
body, section, aside, p {  
    margin: 0;  
    padding: 0;  
}  

main {  
    width:90%; /* viewport is 1264px wide, 90% width is 1137.590px */  
    background-color: lightgreen;  
    min-height: 1000px;  
    margin: 0 auto;  
}  

section {  
    height: 500px;  
    width: 44.067133%; /* 500/1137.590 */  
    background-color: green;  
    float: left;  
    margin: 04.398736%; /* 50.031/1137.590 */  
    padding: 5%; / 25/500 */  

}

aside {  
    height: 300px;  
    width: 26.434279%; /* 300/1137.590 */  
    background-color: blue;  
    float: right;  
    margin: 04.398736%; /* 50.031/1137.590 */  
    padding: 8.3333333%; /* 25/300 */  
   color: lightblue;  
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>

    <section class="box-green">
      <p>This is a green box</p>
    </section>

    <aside class="box-blue">
      <p>This is a blue box</p>
    </aside>

  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Note that it is **required** to post your markup here and, if you used github, that would get this question closed. [mcve]

Comment: Ah ok, good to know. Thanks

Comment: You may want to look into using SASS or LESS, so you can use variables in your stylesheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Padding, when given in percents, is based on the containing element not the height of the element itself.

Comment: Wow that worked. I thought that's how you calculate margin % but that when it comes to padding you use the size of the element itself. I just took an online course that stated that exact point which is weird.

Answer (score 1):

When you calculate padding in percentage, that amount is calculated by the width of the containing block, not the height.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding

Comment: It was my understanding, through an online course I just took, that you calculate the padding % by the size of the element itself, not the containing element, which I understand is how you calculate the margin. The course must have been wrong so...

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not the correct way to write a responsive code but just to make you understand the padding % is not determined from the div size but its determined from the screen size. Also the margin you are using 4.398736% is adding on both left and right side of both the divs. Plus the padding of 5% on both side of .section and padding of 8.33333% on both side of .aside. its making the total size to 115.96555%.

For your understanding if you want both the divs (section and aside) to align side by side. Use the below written css style for both of them.

```
.section {
height: 500px;
width: 44.067133%;
background-color: green;
float: left;
margin: 02.199736%;
padding: 5%;
display: inline-block;
}

.aside {
height: 300px;
width: 26.434279%;
background-color: blue;
float: right;
margin: 02.199736%;
padding: 5%;
color: lightblue;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thanks. It seems the padding is calculated by the size of the container, not the screen or div size. An online course I've been taking explicitly stated that you calculate the padding % by the element's size which seems to be totally wrong. What's your reasoning for adding display: inline-block?

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I missed that you have a container as well. I thought you are putting the divs directly under body.